# How to make both col-xs-12 and col-xs-6 depending on the screen size below 768px

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3.

For one of my webpages, I want to use `col-xs-12` for `319px-544px` and `col-xs-6` for `545px-768px`... but this is obviously not feasible since `col-xs-` is applied to everything `<768px`.

Apparently this is addressed in bootstrap 4, but my whole app is written for bootstrap 3 up until this point.

It is very difficult to be limited to the same column formats at `319px` **and** `767px`. Is there anyway around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with this code

```css
.col-xsm-12{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
 min-height:1px;
 padding-right:15px;
 padding-left:15px
}
}
@media screen and (min-width: 319px) and (min-width: 544px){
.col-xsm-12{
  width:100%;
}
}
@media screen and (min-width: 545px) and (min-width: 767px){
.col-xsm-12{
  width:50%;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xsm-12">
```

Comment: there is a typo, you wrote `min-width` 4 times and also have an extra `}`

Answer (score 3):

Here are two possible ways of achieving this:

**Method #01:**

1. Go to [Customizing Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/customize) page.
2. Move to [Media queries breakpoints](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#media-queries-breakpoints) section.
3. Override the default value of `@screen-sm` varaible with the value that you need i.e. `545px`.
4. Move to [Download](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#download) section and press **"Compile and Download"** Button.

Now All your `col-sm-*` grids will start from 545px instead of 768px.

**Method #02:**

You will need to override Bootstrap styles in your custom css file.

```
@media (min-width: 545px) {
  .col-sm-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

@media (min-width: 545px) {
  .col-sm-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
      <div class="bg-info">
        Column 1
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
      <div class="bg-info">
        Column 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```